# How can I project a circle in 3D world coordinates to 2D image plane if circle center, radius and normal vector from center is known?

Tags: geometry, projection

I have a circle in 3d world and I want to project it to 2D image plane. I have circle center, radius and normal vector from the circle that lets me know the orientation of the circle. Rotation and translation is also known but I don't know how to project it to 2D image plane with these information.

For now, I am finding the circumference points of circle in 3D and project the points. This might be cumbersome so I want to project it as a circle.

Comment: This is a math problem, not C++ problem. What about [Formula for ellipse formed from projecting a tilted circle onto the xy plane](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2389317/423964)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.